# Opensource Java or Ruby Web based Virtual Class Room Components?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

Is there any ruby or Java  Web based Virtual Class Room Components like

1.Whiteboard

2.Instant Messaging

3.Hand Raising Tool

4.Marker

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into project wonderland ([http://www.openwonderland.org](http://www.openwonderland.org/)).

It's a pretty good virtual world that could be used as a virtual classroom.

They use it at MIT to simulate a physics classroom where you can see em-fields, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are few interesting projects in github.
https://github.com/search?q=virtual+classroom

Answer (score 0):

Try this apache project also: http://openmeetings.apache.org/